# White text box with semi-transparent black bg - lightbox needed?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to work with my android app and I need to code the html/css for it; once you interact with the extension you can add tags to a certain page, kinda like pocket.

I've managed to create the footer but now I'm stuck with the adding tags html/css, do I need to use lightbox to achieve the following look: [image]

If not, any tips or tutorials on what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

insert 2 div's: CSS

```
/* ID OVERLAY */
#overlay {
position absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000; /* or transparent pixel 
opacity: 0.3; /* your transparecy */
z-index: 1000; /* Must just be higher than your layout, 1, 2, whatever */
}

/* ID Lightboxlike Content */

#LBcontent {
position relative;
top: 200px;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background: #fff;
margin: auto;
z-index: 2000; /* Higher than the first one #overlay */
```

}

No lightbox needed

greetz

T